# proof verification, relative open sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

This is an exercise from the book point set topology of John B. Conway.

The definitions are these.

if $(X,d)$ is a metric space, a subset $G$ of $X$ is open if $\forall x \in G$  $ 
 \exists r>0 $ s.t $B(x; r) \subseteq G$, a subset $F$ of $X$ is closed if its complement $X\setminus F$ is open.

if $Y \subseteq X$, $(Y, d) $ is also a metric space and $B_Y(y;r) = \{z \in Y: d(z,y) < r \} = B(y; r) \cap Y$

Proposition.
Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $Y$ be a subset of $X$.

(a) A subset $G$ of $Y$ is relatively open in $Y$ if and only if there is an open subset $U$ in $X$ with $G = U ∩ Y$.

(b) A subset $F$ of $Y$ is relatively closed in $Y$ if and only if there is a closed subset $D$ in $X$ such that $F = D ∩ Y$.

Proof:

a) Since $G$ is open in $Y$, $\forall y \in G$ $\exists r_y > 0 $ s.t $B_Y(y; r_y) \subseteq G$, let $P = \bigcup\{B(y;r_y): y \in G\}$, $P$ is open because $B(y;r_y)$ is open and the union of open sets is open, also $P$ is a subset of  $X$, now, in order to prove that $P \cap Y = G$, I proved $(P \cap Y) \subseteq G$ and $G \subseteq (P \cap Y) $.

Let $x$ be any element of $P \cap Y$, therefore $x \in P \land x \in Y$, if $x\in P$, then $x$ is at least in one open ball $B(y; r_y)$, so $x\in B(y; r_y) \land x \in Y$, which is by definition $x \in B(y; r_y) \cap Y = B_Y(y; r_y)$ but $B_Y(y; r_y) \subseteq G$, therefore $x \in G$ and $(P \cap Y) \subseteq G$

Now let $y$ be any element of $G$, therefore, there exists $B_Y(y; r_y) \subseteq G$, so $y \in B_Y(y; r_y) = B(y; r_y) \cap Y$, since $P$ is the union of all such open balls, $y \in P \land y \in Y \rightarrow y \in P \cap Y$, it follows $G \subseteq (P\cap Y)$, therefore $G = P \cap Y$

Now the other way. Let $P$ be an open subset of $X$ such that $G = P \cap Y$
let $x$ be any element of $G$, so $x \in P \land x \in Y$, $P$ is open, thus, there exists an $r > 0$ such that $B(x; r) \subseteq P$, so $x \in B(x; r) \land x\in Y \rightarrow x \in B(x;r) \cap Y = B_Y(x;r) \subseteq G$, therefore $G$ is open in $Y$.

b) Let $F$ be a closed subset of $Y$, so $Y\setminus F$ is open, therefore $\forall y \in Y\setminus F$ $\exists r_y > 0 $ s.t $B_Y(y; r_y) \subseteq Y\setminus F$, let $D = \bigcup\{B(y;r_y): y \in Y\setminus F\}$, so $D$ is an open subset of $X$ and $X\setminus D$ is a closed subset of $X$. We also have $D \cap Y = Y\setminus F$(proved in a),  Now  I prove that $X\setminus D \cap Y$ is a subset  of $F$ and vice versa.

Let $x$ be any element of $X\setminus D \cap Y$, therefore $x \in X \land x \in Y \land x \notin D $, since $Y \subseteq X$, it is the same as saying that $x$ is just in $Y$, so we have $x\in Y \land x\notin D$, if $x$ is in $D$, then $x$ is in $Y\setminus F$ because $D \cap Y = Y\setminus F$, therefore if $x$ is not in $D$, then $x$ cannot be in $Y\setminus F$, thus $x$ is in $F$ and $(X\setminus D \cap Y) \subseteq F$.

Let $x$ be any element of $F$, again, by $D \cap Y = Y\setminus F$, $x$ can't be in $D$, and since $F$ is a subset of $Y$ which is a subset of $X$, $x$ is in X, therefore $F$ is a subset of $X\setminus D \cap Y$ and $X\setminus D \cap Y = F$

Let $D$ be a closed subset of $X$ and $F = D \cap Y$, therefore $X\setminus D$ is open and for any element $y$ in $X\setminus D$, there is an $r >0$ with $B(y;r) \subseteq X\setminus D$, now the set $B(y;r) \cap Y = B_Y(y;r)$ is contained in $Y$ and since  $F = D \cap Y$,  $B_Y(y;r)$ can't have any elements of $F$ (because  $B_Y(y;r)$ doesn't have any elements of $D$) therefore  $B_Y(y;r) \subseteq Y\setminus F$, so $Y\setminus F$ is open in $Y$ and $F$ is closed in $Y$, which completes the proof.

I'm sorry if it's too long, it took me around 2 hours to prove it and I want to make sure it's correct. thank you for taking the time to read the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proofs look good to me. I see no mistakes.